# KeyPress Event Not Working On Image Control in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have tried to get key press event on image control in asp.net. But its not firing when the keys are pressed. My code is:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function keyPress(e) { alert('hi'); }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>        
    <img id="img1" alt ="" width="950" height="950" onkeypress="keyPress();"  src="Images/090069_0709152912.jpg" />        
</div>    
</form>
</body>
```

Kindly suggest to achieve it

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET - that is standard HTML/Javascript. Anyway, you are trying to call keyPress with no arguments but it expects one (e) so no matching function is found. Either remove the parameter OR pass it in when you call it.

Comment: @KevinMain This isn't Java or ASP.NET. You don't need to match arguments to match a function. All arguments are optional, technically. Function names just need to match

Comment: The real problem is that images aren't focusable, so I don't think a `keypress` event can happen on them.

Comment: @Ian that works?! Wow..JavaScript is even worse than I thought. I retract my answer.

Comment: @KevinMain Haha yeah. You can define a function with no parameters, but pass it 10 arguments. And it's no different than calling the function with 5 arguments (except that there are 5 less arguments). The definition of the function determines how many of the numerous arguments you want to be able to reference by name. And either way, you can access all arguments passed with `arguments`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: In addition to the answer that's posted, you can give the image a `tabindex` attribute, which makes it focusable. Here's a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/3V4WC/ - notice how the console log only occurs if the image is first focused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to listen to an element that will not have focus and will not fire a keypress event. Here's an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/V5q9c/) - You'll notice that the alert fires for the document event, but never actually alerts "test" because we cannot fire the keypress event on the image.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may have some options. If all you want to do is listen globally for certain keys to change your image, then you can bind the event to the document and check for certain keys within that event handler.

```
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    //code here
};
```

[**Here's**](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) a nice site to help with determining key codes.